# How to set value in dropdown in jQuery autocomplete combobox

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, drop-down-menu, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I'm using struts and jquery in my application. I have a 2 screens, both have tables and columns.

First screen outputs a bunch of columns, One of the column is a clickable. When user clicks on it, it takes the user to a second screen, so I passing the "Filename" value to the next screen using javascript/struts.

**firstScreen.js**

```
function senderNameClick() {

$(".senderName").click(
        function() {

            event.preventDefault();

            var startDate = $("#datepicker").val();
            var endDate = $("#enddatepicker").val();
            var senderName = $(this).text().trim();


            var dt = new Date();

            window.location.href = 'exceptiondetail?time='
                    + dt.getTime() +'&startDate='
                    + startDate + '&endDate=' + endDate + '&senderName=' + senderName;

        });

}
```

I'm able to get the value in the second screen, but I can't use that value to set it as my jQuery drop down value.

**secondScreen.js**

```
        var senderNameVal = $("#senderName").val();
          $("#filter").val(senderNameVal);
```

**second_screen.jsp** This is how the drop down is outputted in IE Dev tools

```
<select name="" id="filter">
     <option value="ACTIVE">ACTIVE</option>
     <option value="All">All</option>
     <option value="2DG">2DG</option>
     <option value="RACH">RACH</option>
     <option value="FICM">FICM</option> 
</selected>
```

So when the user click on '2DG' the screen screen should be set to '2DG' and data should be filtered based on that value.

**jQuery Code**

```
function setupWidget() {
$("#filter").combobox({
    selectonly : true,
    select : function(event, ui) {
        filterData($(this));
    },
    changed : function(event, ui) {
        filterData($(this));
    },
    textdata : function(event, ui) {
        filterData($(ui.item));
    }
});

filterData($("#filter"));
}

function filterData(element) {
var tblData = $("#datadisplay").data("tableEffects");
var value = element.val();
if (value === "" || value === "All") {
    $(element).disabled = true;
    tblData.clearFilter();
    tblData.restripe();
    $(element).disabled = false;
    $("#filterValue").html(value);
    $("#filterRows").text(tblData.rowCount());
    $("#filterStartRows").text(tblData.startPageItem());
    $("#filterEndRows").text(tblData.endPageItem());
} else {
    $(element).disabled = true;
    tblData.applyFilter(value);
    tblData.restripe();
    $(element).disabled = false;
    $("#filterValue").html(value);
    $("#filterRows").text(tblData.rowCount());
    $("#filterStartRows").text(tblData.startPageItem());
    $("#filterEndRows").text(tblData.endPageItem());
}

  }
```

Comment: When you say a combobox, are you talking about the widget https://jqueryui.com/selectmenu/ ?

Comment: @Taplar https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#combobox

Comment: Where is `event` defined?

Comment: Also where is the code that defines the Autocomplete?

Comment: The HTML close tag is incorrect: `</selected>`. You must close a `<select>` tag with `</select>`.

Comment: Also I do not see where `setupWidget()` is run

Comment: It's a huge js file, Its been called in a document.ready function.